# Remote debug C/C++ on an embedded system

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb

I have to work on a SOM module with Debian installed. I found a [good instruction (video) on how to enable remote debug with an embedded system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9yFyWsyyGk). I followed the steps to set up the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers to work with the module. I tested it with the helloworld project. It worked, great.

Now I started debug my own project. With the same settings, it does not work on my project. I got file input/output error:

[image: Problem Ouccured]

I could not debug it. I then checked target device, found that the binary code was downloaded to the SOM without the X property. After `chmod a+x`, the code ran.

So I'm lost here. Why the remote debug works on the one line helloworld code, and not work for a real project?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no solution for you, but when you find one, assuming it's not an answer here, please post the solution. There is a severe lack of good answers on how to beat Eclipse into submission.

Comment: the problem is usually found by repeatedly cutting the code in half and trying each one separately, narrowing down to something small and specific.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in the remote absolute file path field during the debug configuration. I thought the path does not include the file name, but not the case here. It actually needs the full path and the filename of the application. After I correct that. Everything works. 
[Need file name in the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VXzx.png)

In case someone else need the instruction on setting up remote debug in eclipse. The video by Derek Molloy on Youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9yFyWsyyGk) helped me a lot.